# Cancel intent not invoked Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am writing an `Alexa` skill and having trouble with the `AMAZON.CancelIntent` intent.

If I say "quit" or "help" the other intents get invoked accordingly. But if I say "cancel" my custom intent, `NutriFactsIntent`, gets invoked and of course has issues because the slot is not filled.

**Why does this happen?**

**Intent schema**

```
"intents": [
{
  "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
  "samples": [
    "Cancel",
    "Never mind",
    "forget it"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
  "samples": [
    "Open",
    "Start",
    "what can I say",
    "help me"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
  "samples": [
    "Quit",
    "Exit",
    "Leave",
    "Off",
    "Stop"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "NutriFactsIntent",
  "samples": [
    "give me the facts on a {Food}",
    "give me the facts on an {Food}",
    "give me the facts for a {Food}",
    "give me the facts for an {Food}",
    "give me the facts of a {Food}",
    "give me the facts of an {Food}",
    "give me the facts for {Food}",
    "give me the facts of {Food}",
    ...

}
```

**Catch intent**

```
function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {
    //console.log(`onIntent requestId=${intentRequest.requestId}, sessionId=${session.sessionId}`);

    const intent = intentRequest.intent;
    const intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;

    // Dispatch to your skill's intent handlers
    if (intentName === 'NutriFactsIntent') {
        getFactsFromSession(intent, session, callback);
    } else if (intentName === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent') {
        getWelcomeResponse(callback);
    } else if (intentName === 'AMAZON.StopIntent' || intentName === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent') {
        handleSessionEndRequest(callback);
    } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid intent');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you ty utterences in sample utterences instead of samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted out of the **Launch Skill Builder** BETA that Alexa has available for the Interaction Model.

[image]

I had clicked on that to enter the BETA, I then went to the dashboard after a few hours of suffering and left the BETA.

Now everything works.